# Removing newlines from text before speech

Tags: python

Python 3.7, Windows 7. Beginner.

I'm trying to make a simple program to turn texts into speech 
and save it as an mp3. With the eventual aim of converting books into mp3s.

I can load a text file into a string, and gtts plays and saves it.

The problem is, that at the end of every line the letter "n" is spoken.
The voice is saying the newline character.

One way around it is to have the original text all in one long line, e.g. no newlines, but this is a bit naff and impractical.

I tried reading the docs at 
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/gtts/latest/gtts.pdf

but to be honest I couldn't make much sense out of it, I'm still a beginner.

I have found a function though, that works perfectly on its own,
the trouble is no matter what I try I can't integrate it into my little program as whatever I try does not remove the newlines.

I have tried dozens of methods from this and other googled sources, none work
for me, or I can't understand it.

This code works, except the voice says the "\n" after each line.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

f = open("c:\\temp\\test.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()                          

tts = gTTS(text=str(lines),lang='en-uk')
tts.save("test.mp3")
os.system("start test.mp3")
```

I found this function here:
https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/file/python-io-exercise-17.php

```
def remove_newlines(fname):
    flist = open(fname).readlines()
    return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist]

print(remove_newlines("test.txt"))
```

Which works perfectly on its own, how can I slot this in my code please?

BTW, shouldn't there be a close file in that function?

Comment: Why dont you replace "\n" with space. i think space give's you some pause. use replace instead of rstrip. and do the following flist = open(fname).read().replace("\n"," "). One more thing i think of is, in window's line endings are "\r\n", may be try with that

Comment: Works perfect inaflash, seems so simple now, I just spent 12 hours trying to get that result, I've a lot to learn. Many thanks.

Comment: let me put it as an answer, it might help other's too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do the following changes with the remove_newlines function

```
def remove_newlines(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return f.read().replace("\n"," ")

print(remove_newlines("test.txt"))
```

One more thing i think of is, in window's line endings are "\r\n", may be try with that

Comment: No trouble with \r for me, haven't come across one yet (win 7).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

def remove_newlines(fname):
    flist = open(fname).readlines()
    return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist]

lines = remove_newlines("c:\\temp\\test.txt")

tts = gTTS(text=str(lines),lang='en-uk')
tts.save("test.mp3")
os.system("start test.mp3")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Tori. I am all sorted from the first answer. But I will put your function in my notebook. cheers ears.

Answer (score 1):

The `s.rstrip(c)` function you see there strips the characters represented by `c` from the right side (that is, the end) of the string `s`. Hence, if the string `s` happens to contain a newline character `'\n'` at the end, then `s.rstrip('\n')` will remove that from the end of the string.

The simple way to apply this to your code is to do

```
lines = remove_newlines("c:\\temp\\test.txt")
```

instead of what you're currently doing,

```
f = open("c:\\temp\\test.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Also, you express surprise that there isn't a close file command in that function. Good observation - I would instead write the function like this:

```
def remove_newlines(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as flist:
        return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist.readlines()]
```

To explain, there are a few things here to unpack. First, the `with` expression is kind of like a try-with-resources in Java - at whichever point the code leaves that scope, it'll automatically close the file, even if there's an error in the middle. Next, the expression in square brackets - that's a *list comprehension*, basically a single-line `for` loop. It just constructs a list where each element is the result of calling `rstrip('\n')` on the corresponding element in `flist.readlines()`.

You should insert the function definition in the code sometime *before* you call it, otherwise python will get confused.

Comment: Thank you for the extra advice and info, I will try to take it all in.